# Error when trying to load anything (images e.t.c.) from virtual directory on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, web-deployment

I have a hybrid application (Asp.net Web Forms + MVC) which is working fine on my local system.

It was working fine on server as well. However, recently it has stopped loading images from one of the virtual directory defined on server.

Rest of the site and images are being loaded without any issue. But whenever I try to load anything from the virtual directory called 'AdImages', the system is giving me following exception.

Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

where XXX is the name of my web project.

As mentioned, rest of the site is working perfectly and images are being loaded and displayed from all other folders.

Comment: Sounds like a difference between your DEV and PROD environments. Is there references to your Web project DLL in web.config?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i noticed that this is happening because of few httpModules in my application. When i created a web.config inside my virtual directory and excluded them by adding following line  <modules> <remove name="MyHttpModule"/></modules>, i started getting images :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i noticed that this is happening because of few httpModules in my application. When i created a web.config inside my virtual directory and excluded them by adding following line, i started getting images.

"< modules > < remove name="MyHttpModule"/>< /modules>"